# Radio Button in a php loop not working

Tags: php, loops, radio-button

I am trying to process information captured from a form, but it's not working. I am not getting any information from the form.

I have the following code for the form:

```
<form class="customform" action="" method="post">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

        <tbody>

            <?php foreach($question_row->results() as $test)  { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $test->question?></td>
            <td width="30%">
                <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $test->id ?>]" value="<?php echo $test->categoryId?>"> Yes
                <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $test->id?>]" value="0"> No
            </td>
            </tr>

      <?php   } ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate()?>">
    <div class="s-4"><button type="submit">Submit</button></div>


</form>
```

The following is how I process the form:

```
<?php

require_once 'core/init.php';

$question = new Question();

$question_row = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM questions");


if(Input::exists()) {
if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $user = new User();

   try{
         $_SESSION['food'] = Input::get('question[1]');
         Redirect::to('test');

     }catch (Exception $e)
     {
         die($e->getMessage());
     }

}
}
```

I checked the form output with firebug and everything is correct.  Now when I try to process the form the submit button has been clicked, I don't get an error, the information from `Input::get('question[1]')` is not being passed to the session variable. I assigned `Input::get('token')` to the session variable and it worked. am I doing something wrong on this line:

```
<td width="30%">
                <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $test->id ?>]" value="<?php echo $test->categoryId?>"> Yes
                <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $test->id?>]" value="0"> No
            </td>
```

I've been looking at it for hours

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating array of element with index and you are checking post variable with static index value. Its better you create simple array of element like

```
<input type="radio" name="question<?php echo $test->id ?>" value="<?php echo $test->categoryId?>"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="question<?php echo $test->id?>" value="0"> No
```

and validate post value with isset condition like

```
isset($_POST["question".$test->id])?"":"";
```

Comment: Is there a reason why I can't do it with an array ? the reason I was checking with the a static index value is because I know that index exists

Comment: basically i want to say that radio buttons passes post data only when they selected that is why you do not need to create indexed array of element. And you need to check all values for questions which has been selected. So need to check all questions. I hope it will help you.